# Firefox selenium webdriver gives "Insecure Connection"

Tags: java, maven, selenium, firefox

I've created a Maven project with 20 tests made with Selenium Webdriver (java). Now, when I want to execute my Maven project, I get sometimes the following error:

[Mozilla error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2ktl.jpg)

This is due to login every test. So, when I want to run 20 tests, sometimes that error appears and I can't continue my test, so it returns "Failed test" in Selenium Webdriver.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?
I've tried to put "Thread.sleep(30000);" at the end of every test to give them some time "not to seem a robot", but it doesn't work...

Thanks so much for your help guys!

Comment: Can you just ignore that message and continue on?

Comment: And how could I do that? This is a new tab, it opens and it stops the test. I don't know how to ignore it...

Comment: Ok, you mean its not taking to the desired URL but to this page(the image in the question).. Then, can you try updating the browser and driver and check

Comment: I tried with: 
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
     capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
     capabilities.acceptInsecureCerts();

but it still doesn't work. I've updated the browser and nothing new happens.

Comment: can you also try without any desired capabilities

Comment: yes. actually, at the beginning, I didn't use desired capabilities, but I got the same error. So, I keep trying new ways to solve it.

Comment: Is this different behaviour is happening only for the site that u want to test or for all other sites?

Comment: This is happening with the only web pages that I want to test.

This is the new tab that I get:
https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/01/20/communicating-the-dangers-of-non-secure-http/

How could I ignore or close that tab (to return to my current login tab) with Selenium Webdriver??

Thanks so much!!

Comment: can i have that URL?

Comment: It's the page of my job. Although I told you, you need user&password. I've tried writing "httpS:..." in the URL, but it doesn't exist, so it doesn't work neither...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

### The Real Issue:

1. The URL/Connection with which you are a working if it is `Not Secure` then whenever you access the URL through Mozilla Firefox 53.0, Firefox will display a lock icon with red strike-through red strikethrough icon in the address bar. Now when URL gets loaded the cursor by default will be positioned on `Username` field and there will be popup showing a message `This connection is not secure. Logins entered here could be compromised. Learn More` like this:

[image]

2. Now your script through Selenium enters the username within the `Username` input field and the `Not Secure` popup overlays the `Password` input field.
3. Next if you try to call the `click()` or `sendKeys()` operation in the `Password` input field the `Not Secure` popup receives the click and [**`Insecure password warning in Firefox`**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/insecure-password-warning-firefox?as=u&utm_source=inproduct) page opens up in the next tab along with Selenium shifting its focus to new tab. Hence test-case starts **Failing**.

[image]

### Solution:

In these cases the best solution is:

1. Create a new Mozilla Firefox Profile. You will find the [documentation here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles). For Example, I have created a Firefox Profile by the name `debanjan`
2. Configure the Firefox Profile `debanjan` to ignore all the `UntrustedCertificate` issues.
3. Rerun your Test Script without any issues.
4. Here is a sample code block to disable `insecure_field_warning`:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
   ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
   FirefoxProfile testprofile = profile.getProfile("debanjan");
   testprofile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
   testprofile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true);
   testprofile.setPreference("security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled", false);
   DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, testprofile);
   dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
   WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   driver.navigate().to("http://demosite.center/wordpress/wp-login.php");
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: This should fix the OP up.

Comment: How do you know so much?? O_O, it works perfectly. Thanks so much for your help. You've saved me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I did it but as I am new here, it's not shown. But, I checked in green!! Thanks so much :)