# Your connection is not secure - using Selenium.WebDriver v.3.6.0 + Firefox v.56

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium-webdriver, ssl-certificate

I'm writing tests with **Selenium + C#** and I face an important issue because I didn't found  solution when I test my site with secure connection (**HTTPS**). All solutions I found on stackoverflow are out of date or doesn't work.
I tried to exercise all solutions from below question: 
[Selenium Why setting acceptuntrustedcertificates to true for firefox driver doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583795/selenium-why-setting-acceptuntrustedcertificates-to-true-for-firefox-driver-does)

But they did not help me solve the problem
Nor is it the solution of using Nightly FireFox.
Still, when the selenium loading Firfox browser, I see the page: "Your connection is not secure".

**Configuration:**

- *Firefox*   v56.0
- *Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver*   v0.19.0
- *Selenium.WebDriver*   v3.6.0

my code is:

```
                    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
                    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
                    profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
                    profile.AssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer = false;
                    options.Profile = profile;
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService() , options , TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                    Drivers.Add(Browsers.Firefox.ToString() , driver);
```

Thank for your help!

**Updates to my question here:**

***Note 1:*** To anyone who has marked my question as a duplicate of this question:

[Firefox selenium webdriver gives “Insecure Connection”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44716870/firefox-selenium-webdriver-gives-insecure-connection)
I thought that it is same issue, but I need solution for C#, I try match your JAVA code to my above code

First, I changed to TRUE the below statment:

```
     profile.AssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer = true;
```

second, I create new FF profile ("AutomationTestsProfile")
and try to use it:

Try 1:

```
       FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfileManager().GetProfile("AutomationTestsProfile");
```

try 2:

```
       FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile("AutomationTestsProfile");
```

I Run 2 options, but still the issue exists.

***Note 2:*** I attached screenshot of my problem, it appears when the driver try to enter text to user-name on login page.

I noticed that when I open my site with FF, Firefox displays a lock icon with red strike-through red strikethrough icon in the address bar,

but near the username textbox not appears the msg:

"This connection is not secure. Logins entered here could be compromised. Learn More" (as you writed on the duplicate question),

**So maybe there is a different problem?**

[image: screenshot: "insecure Connection" tab]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are setting the properties on the profile. The FirefoxOptions has a property AcceptInsecureCertificates, set that to true.

Forget the profile, this is what you want:

```
var op = new FirefoxOptions
{
    AcceptInsecureCertificates = true
};

Instance = new FirefoxDriver(op);
```

Comment: Thanks Jota, been looking for this solution for ages!

Comment: Thank you! It Works. But I don't understand why I need to set it to true, if in the FirefoxProfile Class documentation they writes  "Set to true by default"?

Answer (score 3):

For me, the profile setting `AcceptUntrustedCertificates` was not enough, I also had to set option `security.cert_pinning.enforcement_level`. My startup looks like

```cs
// no idea why FirefoxWebDriver needs this, but it will throw without
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56802715/firefoxwebdriver-no-data-is-available-for-encoding-437
CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(437);
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = Config.GetConfigurationString("FirefoxBinaryPath"); // path in appsettings

var options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.SetPreference("security.cert_pinning.enforcement_level", 0);
options.SetPreference("security.enterprise_roots.enabled", true);

var profile = new FirefoxProfile()
{
    AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true,
    AssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer = false,
};
options.Profile = profile;

var driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

## It works for me for following settings (same as above):

My env:

win 7

firefox 61.0.2 (64-bit)

Selenium C# webdriver : 3.14.0

geckodriver-v0.21.0-win32.zip

==============================

FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();

options.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";

options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;

new FirefoxDriver(RelativePath,options);