# Not able to accept certificates in Selenium 3.7 C#, Firefox 57

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I have upgraded Selenium and Firefox to the latest but the website I am testing now lands on the "Your connection is not secure" page and I can't get any of the suggestions online to work such as...

```
FirefoxOpts.SetPreference("webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer", true);
FirefoxOpts.SetPreference("webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs", true);
FirefoxOpts.AddAdditionalCapability("acceptSslCerts", true);
FirefoxOpts.AddAdditionalCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
```

I have also tried creating a profile and using...

```
FirefoxProfile profile = profileManager.GetProfile("Selenium");
profile.SetPreference("webdriver.firefox.profile", "Selenium");
```

...but these don't work either. This is using Selenium Grid.

UPDATE

Code block for webdriver initiation is:

```
 var capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
 var FirefoxOpts = new FirefoxOptions();
 var profileManager = new FirefoxProfileManager();
 var profile = profileManager.GetProfile("Selenium");
 //profile.SetPreference("webdriver.firefox.profile", "Selenium");
 //profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
 //profile.AssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer = true;

 //profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
 //profile.AssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer = true;

 //capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);

 //FirefoxOpts.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);

 FirefoxOpts.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
 FirefoxOpts.SetPreference("intl.accept_languages", "en-GB");
 FirefoxOpts.SetPreference("layout.css.devPixelsPerPx", "0.8");

 FirefoxOpts.Profile = profile;
 FirefoxOpts.ToCapabilities();

 //FirefoxOpts.SetPreference("webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer", true);

 //FirefoxOpts.SetPreference("webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs", true);

 //FirefoxOpts.AddAdditionalCapability("acceptSslCerts", true);
 //FirefoxOpts.AddAdditionalCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
 //FirefoxOpts.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptInsecureCertificates, true);

 Driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://" + Config.VM + ":5566/wd/hub"), FirefoxOpts);
```

There's lots I've commented out which I've tried previously but nothing works regarding accepting the certs or launching Firefox with a specified profile

Comment: Can you share your entire WebDriver configuration code block?

Comment: I've updated with webdriver config

Comment: Solution was given in a different post https://stackoverflow.com/a/48405107/2315284, thanks Jota

Comment: Found solution in another post here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48405107/2315284

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by your self signed dev certificate. I started having the same issues with chromedriver. The easiest fix was to add the certificate to the trusted root certificates.

1. run MMC
2. File->Add Snap-in
3. Click certificates and add
4. Go to local computer -> personal -> certificates
5. Locate and highlight your certificate, right click it and copy
6. Paste it into the Trusted Root Authority folder.

Firefox should be happy now.