# How to get rid of the Firefox's "Your connection is not secure" page in "Selenium with JavaScript"

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I am trying to automate a https contained url by using Selenium, WebdriverIO and JavaScript, but it started redirecting to `Your connection is not secure` page.
[image]
I have tried to set `'security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled': false`
 and some other preferences as well in firefoxProfile, but it also didn't help.

firefoxProfile used:

```
firefoxProfile: {
    'media.navigator.permission.disabled': true,
    'media.peerconnection.video.h264_enabled': true,
    'media.navigator.streams.fake': true,
    'dom.webnotifications.enabled': false,
    'media.getusermedia.screensharing.enabled': true,
     setAcceptUntrustedCertificates: true,
     setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer: true,
    'security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled': false 
  },
```

Selenium and Firefox versions:

- "selenium-standalone": "~5.8.0"
- Firefox version : 60.0 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of **`Your connection is not secure`** page you have to set the following flags and add a preference through the firefox profile :

- **`setAcceptUntrustedCertificates()`** flag to `true`
- **`setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer()`** flag to `true`
- **`"security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled"`** preference to `false`

The **`firefoxProfile`** settings will be :

```
firefoxProfile: {
    'setAcceptUntrustedCertificates': true,
    'setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer': true,
  },
```

Additionally you will also have to set the *Preference* **`security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled`** to **false**

You can find a detailed discussion in [**`Firefox selenium webdriver gives “Insecure Connection”`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44716870/firefox-selenium-webdriver-gives-insecure-connection/44723960#44723960)

> **Note** : Ensure that you are using compatible *Selenium Client*, *GeckoDriver* and *Firefox Browser* combination.

Comment: I tried by setting following preferences, but still getting same error - 
`setAcceptUntrustedCertificates: true,
 setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer: true,
 'security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled': false`

Comment: Did you bump up the _Selenium Client, GeckoDriver and Firefox Browser_ versions to the latest releases? Can you update the question with your current configuration?

Comment: Shouldn't `setAcceptUntrustedCertificates` and `setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer` be within single quotes i.e. within `'.....'`? Where thse two attributes were to be **set** directly, `security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled` is a _Preference_ to be set and I guess must be handled differently? Am I right?

Comment: i tried to set `setAcceptUntrustedCertificates` and `setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer`  within single quotes, but `VSCode` complaint about the error and removed it after formatting. :(

Comment: I am afraid :( not accustomed with `webdriver-io` or `VSCode` but implementing the configurations I have provided will definitely solve your issue, did you have a look at the _Java_ discussion I have provided for your reference?

Comment: Thanks.. no issue, yes i have gone through your provided link, but unfortunately we can't use same solution here.